# How to extract version number from an xml attribute with bash

Tags: regex, bash, sed

From this xml string from my `config.xml` file I need to extract the first three digits of the version number:

```
<widget id="com.test.enterprise.test" version="3.0.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
```

I've tried:

```
cat config.xml | grep "<widget"  | sed 's/[^0-9.]*\([0-9.]*\).*/\1/'
```

but this only yields a `.` How would the correct regex look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use regular expressions to parse XML.

```
xmllint -xpath 'string(//*[local-name()="widget"]/@version)' 1.xml \
| cut -f1-3 -d.
```

If you need to specify the namespace, too, use the namespace-uri function:

```
//*[local-name()="widget"][namespace-uri()="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"]
```

Answer (score 2):

GNU grep with PCRE support `\K` don't include left of '\K' in the result

```
grep -Po '<widget.*?version="\K[^"]*' <<< '<widget id="com.test.enterprise.test" version="3.0.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">'
```

To have only first 3 digits

```
grep -Po '<widget.*?version="\K\d*(\.\d*){2}' <<< '<widget id="com.test.enterprise.test" version="3.0.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">'
```

Answer (score 1):

You may grab the digits and dots only after `version="` substring:

```
cat config.xml | grep "<widget"  | sed 's/.*version="\([0-9.]*\).*/\1/'
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/SsQiwY)

**Pattern details**:

- `.*` - any 0+ chars
- `version="` - a `version="` substring
- `\([0-9.]*\)` - capturing group #1 matching zero or more digits or `.`
- `.*`  -  any 0+ chars.

The `\1` backreference will keep Group 1 value in the result.

Answer (score 1):

For first three digits of version:

```
grep -oP 'widget.*version="\K\d+\.\d+\.\d+' xmlFile
3.0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

try following awks too, hope this may help you too.

**solution 1st:** Using match function of awk.

```
awk '{match($0,/version=\"[^"]*/);print substr($0,RSTART+9,RLENGTH-9)}'  Input_file
```

**solution 2nd:** Going through one by one all the fields and then checking for version in them.

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i ~ /version/){gsub(/version=|\"/,"",$i);print $i;next}}}'  Input_file
```

**solution 3rd:** making record separator as space and field separator as (").

```
awk -v RS=" " -v FS="\"" '/^version/{print $2}'  Input_file
```

**solution 4th:** simply substituting all the text from starting to till string version=" then again substituting from " to till end, which will keep only version number in output.

```
awk '{sub(/.*version=\"/,"");sub(/\".*/,"");print}'  Input_file
```

I hope this helps.